# How to handle pressing of the "back" button when the camera is open

Tags: android, android-intent, sdk, android-camera, android-camera-intent

How should I handle the pressing of the "back" button and the camera button? Like, I have an open camera to take a photo, but without capturing of photo I press the hardware "back" button. When this happens, my application crashes.

How should I handle pressing of the "back" button?

```
if (requestCode == 100) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            if (intent == null) {
                // The picture was taken but not returned
                /*Toast.makeText(
                        getApplicationContext(),
                        "The picture was taken and is located here: "
                                + fileUri.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .show();  */              
            } else {
                // The picture was returned
                Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
                temp_photo = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
                image1.setImageBitmap(temp_photo);

            }
        }
        else if(resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED)
        {
                if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
                    startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                }
                else
                {                 
                    finish();
                }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I have edited your question a bit. When you get this crash, is there anything in the LogCat?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following method to tell the application what to do when back button is pressed:

```
@Override
 public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
       if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)) {
           onBackPressed();
       }
       return true;
    }
   @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();
// Enter your code here

}
```

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 1):

You dont have to handle the back press, this is done by the camera app.
Your app is crashing becouse the intent in case of RESULT_CANCELED is null.
If you want to "relaunch" the camera again you should do a new intent:

```
Intent cameraIntent = new  Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST);
```